# Does data travel over the internet when using an AWS IoT Rule that executes a Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot, aws-networking

I am making an IoT Rule in IoT Core that executes whenever it receives data in some test topic `test/topic/`. When executed, it runs a Lambda function that inserts the data in some database. Assume DynamoDB in this example. Is the data travelling through the open internet or through Amazon's private infrastructure when transferring the data from IoT Core to the triggered Lambda function using the IoT Rule? I am trying to keep the data inside Amazon's infrastructure as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the data travelling through the open internet

No.

AWS IoT invokes your Lambda function asynchronously within Amazon's network. There would be no need for AWS to transfer data through the open internet, between its own services.